# How can we list all folders in firebase storage

Tags: javascript, firebase-storage

The official documentation of firebase storage has no provision for displaying **folders** it only provides for **file**. So what can I do in such a case.

Comment: Welcome to community plz read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting the question

Answer (score 1):

That's not correct - it does allow you to display nested prefixes (what you call folders).  The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files#list_all_files) makes this clear in the sample code provided:

```
listRef.listAll().then(function(res) {
  res.prefixes.forEach(function(folderRef) {
    // All the prefixes under listRef.
    // You may call listAll() recursively on them.
  });
  res.items.forEach(function(itemRef) {
    // All the items under listRef.
  });
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
});
```

Above, `res.prefixes` contains the list of prefixes nested under the prefix being listed.  Note that I'm using the correct term "prefix".  Cloud Storage does not really have "folders".